# Copying points fall on line to irregular polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, editing

I have points fall on  a centre line and I need to copy these points to the surrounding border, the polygon falls in irregular distance from the centre line?

[image]

Comment: Do you need two points for each (one either side)?

Comment: Yes Matthew, i need the points in both sides

Comment: If you can break the polygon into two sides as a Line FC and run Near against each side you will have the XY's  needed to create Points on Polygon edges.

Comment: Thank you  klewis
I thought there is a direct tool

Comment: Perhaps you can snap the output from "Perpendiculat Transacts" to your polygon edge? http://gis4geomorphology.com/stream-transects-partial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @klewis:

> If you can break the polygon into two sides as a Line FC and run Near
>   against each side you will have the XY's needed to create Points on
>   Polygon edges.